# How do I fade in a div that has a set opacity?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fadein

I have a div filled with info at [this blog](http://roseannebarr.tumblr.com) and I have it set at a certain opacity using CSS. How would I have it "fade in" using jQuery to 90 or 100% on hover of that div?

```
.infoHolder2 {
position:absolute;
color:#FFF;
background:#9f9377;
padding:15px;
padding-top:23px;
z-index:5;
width:97.7%;
bottom:8px;
margin:-8px;
opacity:0.2;filter:alpha(opacity=20)
}

<div class="infoHolder2"><div id="title">I'm {Title} and I like <span id="stuff"></span>.  
</div><img id="portrait" src="{PortraitURL-128}"><img id="portraitCover"   
src="http://static.tumblr.com/ux4v5bf/3Uolhxkyl/cover.png">
<div id="infoHolder">{Description}</div></div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [jquery fadeto()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeto/).

This should do the trick (fade to 90% in 500 ms):

```
$(".infoHolder2").fadeTo(500, 0.9);
```

Comment: I forgot to mention I want to hover and it fade in on hover.

Comment: Then, try the following script: 


`$(".infoHolder2").hover(function(){$(this).fadeTo(500, 0.9);},function(){$(this).fadeTo(500, 0.2);});`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`fadeTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/).

To fade to 90% opacity, use this...

```
$('.infoHolder2').hover(function() {
    $(this).fadeTo(1000, 0.9);
}, function() {
    $(this).fadeTo(1000, 0);
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/PQwQn/).

Answer (score 0):

Use jQueries `fadeTo`

**Usage**
http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/

```
fadeTo(duration, opacity)
```

**Example**

```
//90% Opacity
$('.infoHolder2').fadeTo("slow", 0.90);

//100% Opacity
$('.infoHolder2').fadeTo("slow", 1);
```

**On Hover**

```
$('.infoHolder2').hover(
        function(){
            $(this).fadeTo('slow', 0.90);
        },function(){
            $(this).fadeTo('slow', 0.50);
        } 
);
```

[***Live Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/bq9qu/3/)

Comment: I forgot to mention I wan't to hover and it fade in on hover.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the following should work:

```
$('.infoHolder2').fadeTo(500,'1');
```

It's worth noting the order of the arguments in the `fade()` method, duration is first, followed by the value of the desired `opacity`. For some reason I *always* get them mixed up when writing them down. Thanks @alex for the comment.

You could, also, if you wanted to, use:

```
$('.infoHolder2').animate({'opacity':'1'},500);
```

But, unless you're animating other properties, it becomes a little less concise for the same effect.

[JS Fiddle demo to cover both options](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Ub59D/).

References:

- [`fadeTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/),
- [`animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

---

**Edited** in response to OP's requirements to run this on `hover()`

```
$('ul li').hover(
    function(){
        var which = $(this).index();
        if (which == 0){
            $(this).fadeTo(500,'1');
        }
        else {
            $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},500);
        }
    },
    function(){
        $(this).fadeTo(500, 0.5);
    }
);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Ub59D/1/).

Comment: You should swap those arguments around, I think :)

Comment: It seemed logical to me at first the target opacity would be the first argument. I wonder if jQuery is getting some argument signature advice from PHP? =}

Comment: I forgot to mention I want to hover and it fade in on hover.

Answer (score 0):

also by CSS3 without using jquery

```
.image {

    position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
        opacity:1;
filter:alpha(opacity=100);

}
.image:hover {

        opacity:0;
filter:alpha(opacity=0);
    }
```

Comment: Wow this is great! I hope all browsers support this soon. CSS is so much easier than messy javascript.

Comment: when you right this code 
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
it's supported in the main browser safari, firefox , opera and Internet explorer .